# How to reference another assembly file and call from it

Tags: c#, cil, mono.cecil

Hey guys so in my experience documentation for Mono.Cecil is semi-rare and I cant seem to find a answer for this anywhere. I am trying to modify one of my Unity3D game's DLL and add a new class, then inject a method called "Update" into that class. Once done I want to insert a IL instruction to call the Input.GetKeyDown bool from unityEngine. But I cant seem to figure out how to ACTUALLY reference it. When I try just doing this:

```
Instruction IL2 = method.Body.GetILProcessor().Create(OpCodes.Call,UnityEngine.Input.GetKeyDown);
```

I get a error with it. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm sure I'm not the only one with this problem.

The full code I have can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/1dug0LmA

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, could you include the code here, instead of linking to it?

Comment: Can't you just change the code in question, add a new class, with the new method, recompile and just use the DLL rather than messing about with IL? What's your use case here for requiring this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this by using

```
asm.MainModule.Import((typeof(<type>).GetMethod("<Method Name>")));
```